# Trying to understand Relative Layouts

Tags: android, adt

Brand new to Android dev, and I'm trying to figure out whats broken with a small piece of code.

I have a Relative Layout (which I believe suits my needs the best). I have two buttons together on a row that I specified in the activity_main.xml file. When I press one of the buttons I'd like to have a EditText field and button repeatedly appear on the same row, below the last set of items. Kinda like this:

> BUTTON             BUTTON
>
> |*_*_|    BUTTON

My function adds the EditText where I expect it on the first tap however I end up with a row of 3 buttons like this:

> BUTTON  BUTTON    BUTTON
>
> |*_*_|

Code is below, am I missing something about Relative Layouts? Am I accessing elements in a horribly botched way even?

```
//Get main layout as defined in activity_main.xml
        final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);


        //Setup rules
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams below = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams right = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      

        newTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                below.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,rl.getChildAt(rl.getChildCount()-1).getId() );

                EditText timerName = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                Button btnAddNewTimer = new Button(MainActivity.this);

                timerName.setText("New Timer");
                timerName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                timerName.setLayoutParams(below);

                rl.addView(timerName);

                right.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,rl.getChildAt(rl.getChildCount()-1).getId());

                btnAddNewTimer.setText("Add");
                btnAddNewTimer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnAddNewTimer.setLayoutParams(right);

                rl.addView(btnAddNewTimer);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't trust the getChildCount()-1).getId() to get the last added view.

Also, you need to specify a layout parameter on where you want your new item to be vertically.  So your you need to add a rule to right that will line up its top with the button.

I'd recommend that you get the id of your added view

```
            timerName.setText("New Timer");
            timerName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            timerName.setLayoutParams(below);
            timerName.setId(39);//or some other unique id in this range
            rl.addView(timerName);


            right.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, timerName.getId());
            right.addRUle(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,timerName.getId());

            btnAddNewTimer.setText("Add");
            btnAddNewTimer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnAddNewTimer.setLayoutParams(right);
```

Comment: Follow up sub question, why that range of 39? I checked the id of the last child and its in the range of 2131230722. Are id's guaranteed to be that large all the time?

Comment: They are large.  I believe that all id's assigned via XML inflation a are restricted to values above 0x00FFFFFF  but I can't find the exact documentation at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Think for some reason, the `right.addRule` is not counting the new child `timerName` added to the view.

As we know the `btnAddNewTimer` needs to be placed to the right of the `timerName` edittext, try passing in the `timerName id` to the `right.addRule`.

So instead of..

```
right.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,rl.getChildAt(rl.getChildCount()-1).getId());
```

Try...

```
right.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, timerName.getId());
```

Hope this helps.